# Xamarin Forms: Content Page Secondary Toolbar Items in iOS same as Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using secondary toolbar items in my content page. I want the same menu items in iOS as in android. By default it is showing under navigation bar. How can I achieve this.

[image]

Comment: That's the design in iOS..I don't think there is a workaround unless you custom the Toobar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution as, I created a custom PageRenderer class.

```
public class RightToolbarMenuCustomRenderer : PageRenderer
{

    //I used UITableView for showing the menulist of secondary toolbar items.
    List<ToolbarItem> _secondaryItems;
    UITableView table;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Get all secondary toolbar items and fill it to the gloabal list variable and remove from the content page.
        if (e.NewElement is ContentPage page)
        {
            _secondaryItems = page.ToolbarItems.Where(i => i.Order == ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary).ToList();
            _secondaryItems.ForEach(t => page.ToolbarItems.Remove(t));
        }
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
    }

    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        var element = (ContentPage)Element;
        //If global secondary toolbar items are not null, I created and added a primary toolbar item with image(Overflow) I         
                // want to show.
        if (_secondaryItems != null && _secondaryItems.Count > 0)
        {
            element.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem()
            {
                Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
                Icon = "more.png",
                Priority = 1,
                Command = new Command(() =>
                {
                    ToolClicked();
                })
            });
        }
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
    }

    //Create a table instance and added it to the view.
    private void ToolClicked()
    {
        if (table == null)
        {
            //Set the table position to right side. and set height to the content height.
            var childRect = new RectangleF((float)View.Bounds.Width - 250, 0, 250, _secondaryItems.Count() * 56);
            table = new UITableView(childRect)
            {
                Source = new TableSource(_secondaryItems) // Created Table Source Class as Mentioned in the 
                                //Xamarin.iOS   Official site
            };
            Add(table);
            return;
        }
        foreach (var subview in View.Subviews)
        {
            if(subview == table)
            {
                table.RemoveFromSuperview();
                return;
            }
        }
        Add(table);
    }   
}
```

Table Source Class is Inherited UITableViewSource

```
public class TableSource : UITableViewSource
{

       // Global variable for the secondary toolbar items and text to display in table row
    List<ToolbarItem> _tableItems;
    string[] _tableItemTexts;
    string CellIdentifier = "TableCell";

    public TableSource(List<ToolbarItem> items)
    {
            //Set the secondary toolbar items to global variables and get all text values from the toolbar items
        _tableItems = items;
        _tableItemTexts = items.Select(a => a.Text).ToArray();
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return _tableItemTexts.Length;
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(CellIdentifier);
        string item = _tableItemTexts[indexPath.Row];
        if (cell == null)
        { cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, CellIdentifier); }
        cell.TextLabel.Text = item;
        return cell;
    }

    public override nfloat GetHeightForRow(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return 56; // Set default row height.
    }

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //Used command to excute and deselct the row and removed the table.
        var command = _tableItems[0].Command;
        command.Execute(_tableItems[0].CommandParameter);
        tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
        tableView.RemoveFromSuperview();
    }
}
```

In View Model I have

```
public ICommand CancelCommand { get; set; }

//In constructor of ViewModel I Created Event for Command 
CancelCommand = new Command(async () => await Cancel());

private async Task Cancel()
{
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

In Content Page Xaml I am using toolbar items as

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text ="Cancel" Priority="1" Order="Secondary" Command="{Binding CancelCommand}"/>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

and The output for the solution is same as I want.

Happy ending :). Please let me know if I can use much better approach. Ready to learn.

Comment: only problem here is user has to tap on tool to close it. do you know if we can achieve to close it if user taps on outside of the popup?

Answer (score 4):

Some changes to Amit Manchanda answer:

Table Source Class is Inherited UITableViewSource

```
public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            //Used command to excute and deselct the row and removed the table.
            var command = _tableItems[**indexPath.Row**].Command;
            command.Execute(_tableItems[**indexPath.Row**].CommandParameter);
            tableView.DeselectRow(indexPath, true);
            tableView.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }
```

custom PageRenderer class.

```
if (_secondaryItems != null && _secondaryItems.Count > 0 **&& element.ToolbarItems.FirstOrDefault(e => e.ClassId == "menu") == null**)
            {
                element.ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem()
                {
                    Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Primary,
                    Icon = "more.png",
                    Priority = 1,
                    Command = new Command(() =>
                    {
                        ToolClicked();
                    })**,
                    ClassId = "menu"**
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks to @Amit Manchanda and @Igor Tsapko. This worked pretty well for me.

I had the same question as @BatMaci. Here's what I did to solve it using the MessagingCenter:

In the RightToolbarMenuCustomRenderer constructor, I subscribed to a message from the MessagingCenter:

```
public RightToolbarMenuCustomRenderer()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<BaseViewModel>(this, AppConstants.str_iOS_TAP_OUTSIDE_CUSTOM_TOOLBAR, CloseRenderedControl);
}

public void CloseRenderedControl(object sender)
{
    if (table != null)
        ToolClicked(); // same as the ToolClicked() method Amit posted
}
```

Then in the markup for my page, I added a ContentView with a TapGestureRecognizer that wraps the view's content, and is bound to a Command.

```
<ContentView>
    <ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnTappedCommand}" />
    </ContentView.GestureRecognizers>
    <StackLayout>
    <ListView .....
```

The command is an ICommand on my BaseViewModel, which is initialized in that VM's constructor, to execute my OnTappedMethod:

```
public BaseViewModel()
{
    OnTappedCommand = new Command(OnTappedMethod);
}

public ICommand OnTappedCommand { protected set; get; }

public void OnTappedMethod()
{
    if(Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
        MessagingCenter.Send<BaseViewModel>(this, AppConstants.str_iOS_TAP_OUTSIDE_CUSTOM_TOOLBAR);
}
```

This pretty much just simulates clicking the custom control closed again. I wanted to post this to save someone some time. I should point out I'm new to Xamarin, and have only tested on one iOS device (iPhone 7 running 12.4.1).